# Having trouble deserializing an object...casting error

Tags: java, casting, objectinputstream

Currently have an Employee class in a package called People that writes details to an object.I created a ReadFile class to read the object,but having trouble casting that throws an error.
It cannot cast to People.Employee

```
Public Class ReadFile{

final String FILENAME = 
"C:\\employee.bin";
public void readFromFile(){
    try{
    FileInputStream fo = new FileInputStream(FILENAME);
    ObjectInputStream os = new ObjectInputStream(fo);
    Employee obj = (Employee) os.readObject();
    os.close();

    System.out.println(obj);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Log the actual type of the object before you cast it (or use a debugger to examine it).

Comment: How you serialize Employee object in file?

Comment: Thanks for replies...I checked re checked my objects and got it working.

Answer (score -1):

Re-checked the objects I was passing in when serializing.
Got it working.